# CIBERSORT runtime error eval failed

Tags: rna-seq, cibersort

I was running [CIBERSORT](https://cibersort.stanford.edu) but caught this error right after it started permutation:

```
org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed, request status: error code: 127
88
```

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, I found that this problem was caused by the fact that the tables are too large!
They really should have designed the correct error messages!